# How do I git branch <branchname> on glob

Tags: git, glob

I'm trying to run:

```sh
git branch -D bugfix/*
```

to delete multiple branches all with the same prefix, but it returns

```sh
zsh: no matches found: bugfix/
```

How do I match regex for this command?

Comment: Side note: `bugfix/*` is technically a *glob expression* rather than a *regular expression*. (Regex is more powerful than glob, so the distinction is useful.) In general one uses tools other than the shell itself, as in [HamiltonPharmD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483003/1256452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would check and ensure my regex is targeting the correct branches:

`git branch | grep "bugfix/"`

Second, after confirming the expected branches are returned, delete them with:

`git branch | grep "bugfix/" | xargs git branch -D`

Answer (score 0):

(I don't really think you need the below, but it will probably shed some more light on git-related scripting besides other answers.)

`git branch` is a high-level, porcelain, command and it is not designed to use in scripts or to be consumed by other commands (despite you can pipe it in any way you wish, and `grep` is one among of them). You can use [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) instead. Moreover, your pattern suits it just perfect so you don't need using `grep`. All you need is:

```sh
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/bugfix
```

This command produces all references started with `refs/heads/bugfix/` (e.g. `refs/heads/bugfiX` won't match the pattern (not sure about Windows though)). Internally, you can refer any branch by their internal name, say a local `ref/heads/master` (or shorter if not ambiguous `heads/master`) or a remote `ref/remotes/origin/master` (or `remotes/origin/master`) etc. Running `git for-each-ref` without the ref-argument will produce all refs, so you can inspect all of them, and see the pattern they all follow.

Another low-level, plumbing, command to update references in git is [`git update-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) that allows manipulating references at low level, where deleting a reference can be accomplished by using the `-d` switch:

```sh
git update-ref -d refs/heads/bugfix/foo
```

Combining the above commands into a single piped command is like:

```sh
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/bugfix | xargs -I{} git update-ref -d {}
```

or

```sh
while read -r REF; do echo "rm $REF $(git rev-parse $REF)"; git update-ref -d "$REF"; done < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/bugfix)
```

(`-I{}` and `{}` is required to make `xargs` to run `git update-ref` for each reference, because `git update-ref` can work with one reference at max unless using the `--stdin` option.)